# ionic ble cannot retrieve name of devices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've written a simple app that scans for ble devices. Everything works fine but my only problem is that the payload I get from the scan does not contain the name of the device, I can only see its mac address.

Like this:

```
    {
        "id":"0C:45:C5:7F:B9:92",
        "advertising":{},
        "rssi":-88
       }
```

Here my scan function:

```
startScan() {
    this.scanList = [];
    this.loadingService.showLoading();

    const scanTime = 10;
    const subscription = this.ionicBle.scan([], scanTime).subscribe((x) => {
      console.debug(`scan result: ${JSON.stringify(x)}`);
      this.onDeviceDiscovered(x);
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadingService.hideLoading();
      console.debug(`about to unsubscribe from scan`);
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    }, scanTime * 1000);

    console.debug(`scanned devices: ${this.scanList}`);
  }

  onDeviceDiscovered(deviceScanned) {
    console.debug(`Discovered devices: ${JSON.stringify(deviceScanned)}`);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.scanList.push(deviceScanned);
      console.debug(`scanlist: ${JSON.stringify(this.scanList)}`);
    });
  }
```

I've tried on my phone using the nRF connect app and I can see the name of the device i am interested in.
Do you have any clue? I am using { BLE } from "@ionic-native/ble"

Comment: This is not unusual. Many BLE devices do not advertise their device name.

Comment: @Risto yes but I don't understand why I can see the device name on the nRFConnect app whilst cannot see it using the app I wrote..

Comment: I think nRF Connect maybe connected to the device before and cached the name. Otherwise, you can show us the raw advertising data from nRF Connect and we can then look at the data together and find out whether the device name is transmitted. By the way: Does your application use the passive or active BLE scan algorithm?

Comment: @Risto Thanks for the insights. At last the problem was firmware side. My colleagues fixed the name of the device in the ble module firmware.